# String Handling with and without "const" key word in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char *p="abc";
    cout<<p;

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me the the desired output "abc". But when I try the below one i.e.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *p="abc";
    cout<<p;

    return 0;
}
```

it gives me a warning

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’[-Wwrite-      strings]
char *p="abc";
```

What's the reason behind this kind of scenario?